# Convert jpeg/png to an array of pixels in java

Tags: java, image, pixel

How can I convert a string containing a jpeg or png to an array (preferably one dimensional) of pixels? Ideally using classes built into java?

Comment: string? in what format? base64? hex?

Comment: Does this string contain the file name of a file, or the raw image data?

Comment: again - in what format ?

Comment: whatever a POST HTTP file submission would be, I'm guessing base 64 encoded?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out you need [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/). Look at the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) for how to obtain the image `InputStream`. From there you can simply call:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(item.getInputStream());
```

From here on there are many ways:

- loop over the image dimensions and for each x and y call `int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);`
- same as above, but call `getRed(x, y)`, `getGreen(x, y)`, `getBlue(x, y)`
- get the `ColorModel` and call the above methods there
- call `getRGB(startX, startY, w, h, rgbArray, offset, scansize)`
- call `getData()`, which returns a `Raster`, and call `getPixes(..)` there

Answer (score 0):

Use [PixelGraber](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html). It returns one-dimensional array of RGB data.