# how to Compare two pdf and save the difference by highlighting in new pdf [Programmatically]?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe, pdfbox

Apart from doing pdf compare using **acrobat pdf compare** and **inet software tool** is their any **free libraries** to do comparing the two pdf's and save the difference by highlighting in a new pdf. Is it possible? I not yet started the coding before starting I have few clarifications to do get the idea from your experts to guide me how to obtain/reach my requirement. I had a few uncleared plans to use C# and third party libraries. Please suggest your idea/guide for obtain this task.

**Compare types are text and visual compare**.

**Program type c#
Library plan to use is itextsharp/pdfbox**

Comment: I doubt this is even possible as PDF are binary files that are quite hard to compare. However even if you *could* compare them, what would it mean to you if `ksdfn,ss,a,msdn,` is different from `masdnkmak/&T(ZUI/`? It could mean so much: different font used, different spacing, even different characters printed or just different colour.

Comment: Take a look at iText's tests to see how we compare pdf files as part of the test suite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, now I will look out the itext about the possibilities.

Comment: @ HimBromBeere, Will see I will trying the itext. let me check and update if I found the action and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@newbee, please refer this link quite useful for the concepts.

[How to compare two PDFs based on visual differences programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311738/how-to-compare-two-pdfs-based-on-visual-differences-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks will try your idea and get back to you if any help  needed